# Why does Visual Studio exit debugging mode after this statement?

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, asyncsocket, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to debug some async code and when I try to step through the lines of code in the debugger, everything goes fine until it reaches Line 18 in the snippet below.  After it runs that line, the debugger stops and VS exits debugging mode. Is there a particular way to debug an async program that I am missing or is there something in the code that is incorrect?

```
1. private static void ReadAsynchronously(IAsyncResult ar)
2.        {
3.            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
4.            //Data buffer for incoming data
5.            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
6.
7.            Socket readHandler = state.workSocket;
8.            
9.            //Flag variable for identifying the End of Character from the read message
10.            bool pFlag = false;
11.
12.            //String variable for store the reading data from the client socket 
13.            string content = string.Empty;
14.            string data = string.Empty;
15.
16.
17.            // Read data from the client socket.
18.            int read = readHandler.EndReceive(ar);
19.
20.            if (read > 0)
21.            {
                   ........
```

Comment: The EndReceive() call will throw an exception to indicate that the async operation failed.  Not sure why the debugger won't tell you about it.  Look in the Output window for a "first chance" exception notification.  Use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to force it to stop.

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't see your comment before my answer, no intention to hijack your kudos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be missing an Exception in the EndRead call, try using a catch block and check:

```
int read;
try
{
    read = readHandler.EndReceive(ar);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); //ADD BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

Comment: You nailed it.  I had accidentally closed the WorkSocket in a finally block located in the BeginRecieve function.   Since the socket was disposed, it threw an uncaught error which made the debugger detach.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you step over a line of code the debugger lets that line of code run and then returns you to a break state. In line 18 what is happening is that the line of code is taking a long time to run so it appears that the debugger has stopped debugging but it hasn't: the debugger will break if and when that line of code eventually completes.

You will need to investigate why that operation doesn't complete or why it is taking so long. The [EndReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx) method will block until data is available so the most likely cause is that the process at the other end of the connection has not actually sent any data.

Edit: If the code doing the sending is your own and you are using a `StreamWriter` then ensure you call `Flush()` after writing to it. Alternatively you can turn on automatic flushing via the `AutoFlush` property.

Comment: I suppose "vs exiting the debug mode" in the question means the application terminates, but you may be right here... @OP: Is VS in break or in stopped state afterwards?

Comment: @eFloh I more interested in whether the application is stopped or in *running* state. We know from OPs description it is not in break state.

Comment: VS was actually exiting debugging mode.  I could tell this because of the play/stop icons that indicate to start/stop debugging in the toolbar, well when it reached that line of code, the Play button was enabled indicating that debugger was detached.